# Start memcached server programmatically from Java or Scala

Tags: java, scala, memcached

Is there some library that easily lets me start a memcached server from (test) code in Java or Scala?

Like Jetty does: start an http server programmatically.
I know Redis has that.

Comment: If you can use docker, maybe try [testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/)?